# How to make a timer start at exactly the same interval according to the clock?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timer

I need help with setting a timer like this:

A timer with 1 minute interval starts at 12:25:25 (HH:MM:SS), the first time it goes off at 12:26:00 and then 12:27:00 and so on. Or take another 15 minute interval timer that starts at 12:07:25 and goes off at 12:15:00 and then at 12:30:00 and so on.

I managed to make the 1 minute timer go off like this:

`OneMinute.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 - DateTime.Now.Second);`

It works perfectly but I still need to calculate how many minutes are left till the clock reaches 15,30,45 or 60.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing and calculations, I was able to successfully get the minutes left till the clock reaches the factor of 15.

Here's how:

`FifteenMinutes.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15 - DateTime.Now.Minute % 15);`

Thank you every one for your help! It was direly needed.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a special initialized timer:

- Calculate the time span to the next desired tick
- Set the initial interval to that time span
- Start the timer
- After the first tick, set the interval to the desired time span.

**StartPlainTimer method**

```
// Define other methods and classes here
private static DispatcherTimer StartPlainTimer(TimeSpan interval)
{
    var millisecondsLeftToday = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    var millisecondsInterval = interval.TotalMilliseconds;
    var firstInterval = millisecondsInterval - ((millisecondsLeftToday / millisecondsInterval) % 1) * millisecondsInterval;
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(firstInterval);
    timer.Tag = interval;
    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now);
    timer.Tick += ResetInterval;
    timer.Start();
    return timer;
}

private static void ResetInterval(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
    timer.Interval = (TimeSpan)timer.Tag;
    timer.Tick -= ResetInterval;
}
```

**Usage**

```
// Example for a timer that runs all 3 seconds
var timer = StartPlainTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
timer.Tick += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

**Output**

```
Start: 02.06.2016 16:26:41
02.06.2016 16:26:42
02.06.2016 16:26:45
02.06.2016 16:26:48
```

---

A more detailed time format shows the inaccuracy of that method:

Example for 15 seconds:

```
Start: 06.02.2016 04:44:50.902 
06.02.2016 04:45:00.017 
06.02.2016 04:45:15.018 
06.02.2016 04:45:30.024 
06.02.2016 04:45:45.022 
06.02.2016 04:46:00.027 
06.02.2016 04:46:15.031 
06.02.2016 04:46:30.036
```

So if an accuracy of 100 ms is enough, that solution should be fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into a framework such as Quartz.net

[Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

The problem with .NET timers since Windows 7 is that they have a ~15ms resolution, so you could see sliding over time, even if you manage to precisely start this at a specific time.

EDIT: Quartz.net sample code

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .WithCronSchedule("0 42 10 * * ?")
    .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

This would build a trigger that fires daily at 10:42. Though this doesn't give you the exact answer you are looking for, you can schedule tasks in a CRON type of way. So you could achieve a 15 minute execution interval like this. You would need to read more documentation to understand this framework though.

Comment: it may be a good suggestion about timing accuracy but you still didnt answer the question.

Comment: If he uses Quartz.net, he could achieve what he is asking for, I think that is an answer in and of itself. I'll provide a code sample.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. I'm very new to providing answers on SO, so I think I need to work on quantifying my responses better.

Comment: This is helpful but I still need a solution to start the timer at a specific interval.

Comment: Quartz provides facilities for starting tasks at a specific interval too.